# What is Maven repository in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Can anyone explain clairly what is `Maven repository` in Android Studio ? I try to understand it but I don't find better explainations.
Last time I needed to add some dependencies in my project and they didn't work untill I added a link to `Maven and Jcenter` in my `build.gradle` file.

It worked parfectly but my question is just to know What is exactly maven and Jcenter in Android Studio ? 
Thanks in advance with your answers.

Comment: They are public repositories, help you to build your project with the correct libraries. In the past you needed to add each library by your own, now with this technology, you just run their commands and you get the libraries based on the version you choose.

Comment: I see how hard it was.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A maven repository is a "repo", public or private, to store libraries, plugins and in general artifacts.
It is not related to Android Studio or another IDE.

[JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) is one of the maven repo.

> JCenter is the place to find and share popular Apache Maven packages for use by Maven, Gradle, Ivy, SBT, etc.

Other common repo used in Android are:

- [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/)
- [Google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html)

In a [gradle script](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#top-level) you can find them in the `repositories` block:

```
/**
     * The repositories block configures the repositories Gradle uses to
     * search or download the dependencies. Gradle pre-configures support for remote
     * repositories such as JCenter, Maven Central, and Ivy. You can also use local
     * repositories or define your own remote repositories. The code below defines
     * JCenter as the repository Gradle should use to look for its dependencies.
     *
     * New projects created using Android Studio 3.0 and higher also include
     * Google's Maven repository.
     */
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: Thank for this answer. I didn't know the difference between Maven and JCenter. Now I understand what is JCenter too.

Answer (score 4):

Im not Java guy but from fast lookup in google:

**Maven** is build and dependency management tool (helps in building project and downloading dependencies).

**Jcenter** looks like repository of available libraries (is source for all dependencies downloaded by maven processes).